# Cannot use 1 (type int) as type *int in field value

Tags: go, types

Why does this yield error? It's the same `int` except the with pointer.

```golang
type Gim struct { Active: *int }
yesVar := Gim{ Active: 1}
// error
// Cannot use 1 (type int) as type *int in field value
```

Although when I use it like this

```golang
type Gim struct { Active: *int }
active := 1 
yesVar := Gim{ Active: &active}
// compiles
```

It compiles and doesn't yield error, any explanation why is that?

Comment: In the first example, the application assigns `1`, a value of type `int`, to a variable of type `*int`.  This causes a compilation error.  In the second example, the application assigns `&active`, a value of type `*int` to a variable of type `*int`.  All is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second example, you are assigning a pointer of integer (`*int`) to a field of the same type (`*int`). However, in the first one, you are assigning an `int` to `*int`. This is a mismatch and you can't do it because the two types aren't the same.
`int` is a type that holds integer values (e.g. `0`, `100`, `-55`, ...), and `*int` is a type that holds **addresses** to `int` values in memory (e.g. address `0x00124215`, ...). So, you can see how both don't actually represent the same type.

If you want to still do it in a single line, you would have to define a function that takes a value and returns a pointer:

```
func GetIntPointer(value int) *int {
    return &value
}

yesVar := Gim{ Active: GetIntPointer(1)}
```

Comment: There are actually 2 ENUM on the database `(0,1)`, so I use pointer, so I will know if it's not used then it will be nil. Thanks for the explanations.